# how to get binary response size using jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, httpclient, response

I have this Jersey client code:

```
        //.accept("application/json")

        ClientResponse response = webResource
                .queryParam("reqtype", "tileBatch")
                .queryParam("protocol", "1")
                .queryParam("sessionid", String.valueOf(uId))
                .queryParam("cookie", String.valueOf(secretKey))
                .queryParam("num", "1")
                .queryParam("t0", String.valueOf(tileId))
                .queryParam("v0", "0")
        .get(ClientResponse.class);


        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }
```

when I surf to this url via the browser I get a binary file as a result.

however when run via code I get this response:

[image]

what should I add to my code client to get the binary response as well?

I'm interested in the binary file size. how can i fetch it from the response?

I saw no `size` attribute.

Comment: What `headers` are present? I'm guessing you'll need to read from the `entity` input stream to get the binary data.

Comment: How do i do that? i only want to know its size

Comment: How do i do that if the content interest me?

Comment: If the server provides it, the content length should be in the response headers and can be retrieved by `response.getLength()`. You can get the entity stream by `response.getEntityInputStream()` or `response.getEntityStream()` depending on the version Jersey that you're using. Read from the stream as you would any `InputStream`.